# *Ng if not updating dom async when request on observable is complete

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use *NgIf to show the info from my observable and I use an Else to show the loading component while it makes the request, but when the request is completed it doesn't change async and the load stays forever unless something that triggers DOM update happens (Like pressing F12 or mouse over a tooltip)

I have in my component:

```
export class ReportComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
    public serviceModel$:Observable<Report>;
    constructor(
        public service: ReportService,
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private translationService: TranslationService,
        private translate: TranslateService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('id'); 
        this.translationService.getSelectedLanguage().subscribe(lang => {
           if (lang) {
              setTimeout(() => 
                this.translationService.setLanguage(lang));
           }
       });
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.service.getReport(this.id).subscribe(data => {
        this.serviceModel$ = this.service.Model$;
        this.loading = false;
    });
}
```

And I have in my html:

```
<div class="col-xl-8">
    <m-report-info *ngIf="(serviceModel$ | async) as model; else 
        loading" #reportInfo [themeItems]="model.themeItems" 
        (updateChartEvent)='updateChart($event)'
        (selectedMenu)="selectedMenuChanged($event)" 
        (selectedSubMenu)="selectedSubMenuChanged($event)"></m- 
    report-info>
</div>
<ng-template #loading>
  <m-portlet>
     <ng-container mPortletBody>
       <m-loading-screen></m-loading-screen>
     </ng-container>
  </m-portlet>
</ng-template>
```

EDIT:
This is the code of my ReportService:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
    export class ReportService extends GenericHttpClientService<Report> {
    protected endpoint: string = '/analysis/report';

    public initializeService(model_: Report) {
        this.Model = model_;
    }

    public getReport(id_: string): Observable<Report> {
        return this.getByID(id_);
    }
```

}

Comment: Please, share the code of "ReportService", I'm pretty sure that "Model$" is not getting updated

Comment: The model is getting updated. My problem is that the page is not updating automatically. But as I said, if you press F12 or do something that triggers the dom, like putting the mouse over a tooltip, when the tooltip shows the page shows my html that are in the NGIF. It's like it isn't getting the information that the observable got updated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that `serviceModel$` is observable. You already subscribed to a service. Are you using nested observables?

And If you are using you are on the wrong direction.

If your services has nested observables use `mergeMap` or similar approach.

Comment: Before, the ideia was using *ngIf="service.Model | async as model; else loading" and I did not have the serviceModel$, but i changed because i thought it was better to have the observable in the report.component.
The serviceModel$ get its info from this:
public get Model$(): Observable<TModel> { return of(this._model); }